# How to properly setup two domains pointing in same application with Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two domains. Let's say `reports.test.com` and `report.test.com` and they point to a single Laravel 5.0 application. Sometimes in my logs files, it's showing `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:` error. **Why is my application logging a NotFoundHttpException?**

These are the location of my logs files

```
 http://reports.test.com/storage/logs/laravel-2018-08-13.log
 http://report.test.com/storage/logs/laravel-2018-08-13.log
```

Comment: What do you mean ? when you do a http request to report.test.com the http response is 404 ?

Comment: sometimes report.test.com is working that time reports.test.com is not workind and vice versa

Comment: look, It is really matter of web server not your backend (laravel),
when request get to the web server It triggers laravel, and laravel make response and give to to web server and web server give it back to client.
so please make sure that for both domain, request comes to your laravel application.
do a die('executed') in your public/index.php file

and request to both of your domains and check if request get to laravel or not.

Comment: Could you give more details about your installation? What are you using as your webserver? Explain a bit more about your setup so we can help you better. Can you show on which route this exception is launched?

Comment: Visitor is hitting a url that is not a part of your website anymore.

Comment: What are you using for webserver (nginx, apache, other)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to correctly go around with it is using one domain as primary, and the second as a redirect to the primary.

- Make sure you have only one instance of your Laravel app installed

#### 1. Choose one of the subdomains as *primary* and the other as *parked* (*secondary*) domain. Lets say that `reports` will be primary.

#### 2. Point both DNS A records to your webserver IP

```
A reports.test.com  123.123.123.123 # IP is just an example
A report.test.com   123.123.123.123 # IP is just an example
```

#### 3. Configure your webserver to redirect to your primary domain

For example, the nginx serverblock will be like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name report.test.com;
    # ...
    rewrite ^ http://reports.test.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

# ... (your main app serverblock)
```

Restart nginx after edit of serverblock `# service nginx reload` with priviledge user.

#### 4. Make sure your .env file uses the primary domain

```
APP_URL="http://reports.test.com"
```

If you are using config cache, update the cache: `php artisan config:cache` with your deploy user.

---

NOTE that you may want to edit as required if you are willing to use HTTPS.